# Do I need to select a sample from the dataset to conduct wilcoxon signed rank test?

Tags: sampling, sample, population, wilcoxon-signed-rank

If I have a dataset of size 600 consisting of all the patients to test whether a new drug is effective, do I need to select a sample from the data, or I may proceed with the whole data to do the testing?

if the dataset consists of only the patients that agreed to take the drug, is that consider as a population or it's actually a sample?
Please help to clear my doubts.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The data set of 600 is a sample. You should have three hundred who took the drug and three hundred who didn't.  There should be a way to pair the patients in the two groups and be able to take the paired difference of the response.  If the data consists of only patients that took the the drug you have no way to compare groups to determine the effectiveness of the drug.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you managed to survey every single relevant patient, you have a sample not population. Yes, I bet you have a sample.

If you want to test whether your new drug is effective, you might need large sample size as random variation must be minmized for obvious reason. Clinical trials typically need a large sample size.

If you chose to subset your data, you lose statistical power and relevant information for no apparent reason. Do you have any reason not to statistically model your 600 patients?